# how to compare the large numbers without using calculator and/or without large calculation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

for the given two multiplication below, what is the relationship (>,< or =) .. between this two multiplication?

```
100210*90021 and 
100021*90210
```

I can simply compare these two results by calculation of multiplication but it is too time-consuming and not an effective way of solving this type of questions.
I want different way of finding the relationship (>,< or =) ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$100210 \cdot90021=(100021+189)(90210-189)=\\=100021\cdot90210+189\cdot 90220-189\cdot 100021$$

Answer (score 3):

In $100210\cdot 90021,$ you multiply $210$ by $90000$ and $21$ by $100000$.

In $100021\cdot09210,$ you multiply $210$ by $100000$ and $21$ by $90000$.

The second one is larger.